# AnimationDrawable scaling down the images to animate

Tags: android, imageview, animationdrawable

I want to animate four images to be displayed in a row. In the layout XML-file I'm creating an ImageView:

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/exercisesAnimated"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
```

In my code I then create the `AnimationDrawable`via

```
private void startAnimation() throws IOException {
    AnimationDrawable animation = new AnimationDrawable();
    String path = "Graphics/" + exercise.getName() + "/";
    InputStream is = getAssets().open(path + "1.jpg");
    animation.addFrame(Drawable.createFromStream(is, null), 800);
    is = getAssets().open(path + "2.jpg");
    animation.addFrame(Drawable.createFromStream(is, null), 800);
    is = getAssets().open(path + "3.jpg");
    animation.addFrame(Drawable.createFromStream(is, null), 800);
    is = getAssets().open(path + "4.jpg");
    animation.addFrame(Drawable.createFromStream(is, null), 800);
    animation.setOneShot(false);

    ImageView imageAnim = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.exercisesAnimated);
    imageAnim.setBackgroundDrawable(animation);

    animation.start();
}
```

So my problem is that the animated images become really small, like 1/3 of the original size of the images. These have a size of 460x250, I want them to be shown in that size.

If I just put a `android:src="@drawable/oneOfTheImages"` to the ImageView and dont do the animation the image is displayed in the correct size.

What's wrong?

Comment: Why putting your jpg files in assets ? why don't you simply use the res/drawable/ folder ?

Comment: I needed subfolders, which are not possible in res/drawable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try putting your jpg files in the res/drawable-nodpi folder and pull them as Drawables in the startAnimation method like this :

```
getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.1) // this will pull the 1.jpg file and return a Drawable
```

Comment: Thanks, they are still not in the original size but at least I can scale the ImageView now, so I'm fine.